# php CLI arguments Issues

Tags: php, linux, command-line

I'm working on a command-line script for a php app.

I can't get it to successfully accept params.

(via ssh)

If I type:

/: php testFile.php arg1 arg2 arg3

I receive the following errors:
Notice: Undefined variable: agrc in /testFile.php on line 3
Notice: Undefined variable: agrv in /testFile.php on line 3

Here's the current code:

```
<?php
echo ini_get('register_argc_argv');
print_r( $agrc );print_r( $agrv );
?>
```

I also confirmed that the 'register_argc_argv' directive is TRUE

What am I over looking ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You check for the `argc` and `argv` setting, and then try to debug `agrc` and `agrv`. Look at those variable names again.

Comment: You spelt `argv` and `argc` wrong in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$_SERVER['argv']` instead of only `$agrv`.

Comment: We don't use CGI anywhere in the app now, and the php-cgi binary is not on our server. I believe this can be done using the cli, as well as cgi. Have I misunderstood the cli ?

Comment: Have tried to add `#!/usr/bin/php -q `to the first line of your file , even before the php tag (`<?php`) ? I've updated the answer, check it out.

Comment: Copy & paste your example and it fails - while . Also added the declaration line up top, to no avail. Possibly a directives issue ?

Comment: Try your original code but use `$_SERVER['argc']` instead of only `$agrc`. Does it work ?

Comment: A quick var_dmup shows me it's in
    $_SERVER['agrv']
, that'll work. Thanks Tuga !